# pip ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed

Tags: python, pip, package

I just installed a package using **pip3 install maigret**

i installed another thing using pip3 install but same error

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
crackmapexec 5.2.2 requires bs4<0.0.2,>=0.0.1, which is not installed. 
crackmapexec 5.2.2 requires impacket<0.10.0,>=0.9.23, but you have impacket 0.10.0 which is incompatible.                                  
crackmapexec 5.2.2 requires neo4j<5.0.0,>=4.1.1, but you have neo4j 1.7.0.dev0 which is incompatible.
crackmapexec 5.2.2 requires pylnk3<0.4.0,>=0.3.0, but you have pylnk3 0.4.2 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: OK, so what's your question? If you want your package to have full expected functionality, you'll have to install the correct versions of the dependencies yourself. `pip` can't do it for you. FYI, this is why you should use virtual environments.

Comment: No way Manually???

Comment: Yes. Manually...

Comment: Or you can use a virtual environment dedicated to crackmapexec.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following:

```
pip install <package-name> --use-feature=2020-resolver
```